# syscall return 07 when call _exit

Tags: linux, gcc, nasm, elf, system-calls

I am looking a paper [Size Is EverythingSize Is Everything](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) with kernel 3.8.4 x64 nasm gcc-4.7.2 fedora

by type in moretiny.asm

```
BITS 64

EXTERN _exit
GLOBAL _start
SECTION .text

_start:
    push dword 42
    call  _exit

\>nasm -f elf64 moretiny.asm 
\>gcc -Wall -s -nostartfiles -o moretiny.
\>./a.out ; echo $?
```

7

With gdb help . break at _exit

```
(gdb) display /i $pc
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3a5e0bb750 <_exit>:    movslq %edi,%rdx
(gdb) si
0x0000003a5e0bb753 in _exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3a5e0bb753 <_exit+3>:  mov    0x2f56de(%rip),%r10        # 0x3a5e3b0e38
(gdb) 
0x0000003a5e0bb75a in _exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3a5e0bb75a <_exit+10>: mov    $0xe7,%r9d
(gdb) 
0x0000003a5e0bb760 in _exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3a5e0bb760 <_exit+16>: mov    $0x3c,%r8d
(gdb) 
0x0000003a5e0bb766 in _exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3a5e0bb766 <_exit+22>: jmp    0x3a5e0bb781 <_exit+49>
(gdb) 
0x0000003a5e0bb781 in _exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3a5e0bb781 <_exit+49>: mov    %rdx,%rdi
(gdb) 
0x0000003a5e0bb784 in _exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3a5e0bb784 <_exit+52>: mov    %r9d,%eax
(gdb) 
0x0000003a5e0bb787 in _exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3a5e0bb787 <_exit+55>: syscall 
(gdb) 
[Inferior 1 (process 32082) exited with code 07]
```

seem like the syscall return the code with 07 , I am not sure why .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`x86_64` abi](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/abi_sysV_amd64.pdf) specifies the parameter passing convention.

In this case:

> If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence %rdi,
>   %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9 is used12 .

so you should use the `%rdi` register instead of pushing onto the stack.

This is quite evident from your single-step debugging into the `_exit` function call.

Comment: thank you , I should read the paper you offer . use %rdi can see what i want to see.

Comment: My invocation of `wc -c a.out` at this point still gives a rather hefty 5144 - compared to the 5928 I get with the earlier code which uses main. The (32-bit) article sees a much larger reduction from 2604 to 1340.